# Is there anyway to find the density of histogram values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, histogram, distribution, probability-density

I have 7 vectors ranged between 0 and 0.99. The number of entries in each vector is different, so it would be "unfair" to compare their histograms because there should be a direct correlation between a bin count and the number of entries, assuming the variables are spaced. I'm interested in plotting a smooth curve of the density of the values. So, for a vector a with say n values from 0 and 0.99, I would like an x-axis of 0 to 0.99, with the y-axis being the probabilities associated with those values.

Any ideas or insight?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of smoothing you want, but some idea how to start:

```
%some example vectors of different length
p=[10,100,1000,10000];
D=arrayfun(@(x)(rand(x,1)),p,'uni',false);
%defining the range
support=[0:.1:1];
%make sure we don't miss a value
esupport=support;
esupport(end+1)=inf;
%define a function which uses histc to calculate the emperical probability for each bin
epdf_bin=@(x)histc(x,esupport)/numel(x);
%evaluate emperical probability
E=cellfun(epdf_bin,D,'uni',false);

M=cat(2,E{:});
%plot
bar(M);
%print legend
legend(arrayfun(@num2str,p,'uni',false));
%fix x axis labels
set(gca,'XTick',.5:numel(support))
set(gca,'XTickLabel',support)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to pester you, but is there anyway to smooth this histogram to look like a curve?

Comment: To my understanding it is wrong to draw a curve. You don't have the pdf and you can't get it from the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
[h,b] = hist( my_data, Nbins );
plot( b, h / sum(h) );
```